# The Search Field in datatable is not working on virtual keyboard (Mottie virtual keyboard). What is the possible cause and it's solution?

Tags: datatables, virtual-keyboard

In the data table search input field when I type in using the physical keyboard it performs search by default. But when I type in using the Mottie Virtual keyboard it doesn't perform search but word is there.

I tried to change keypress into keyup and keydown in jquery.keyboard.js

```
$('input[type="search"]').keyboard({
   function(base,$el) {
        base.$el.trigger(base.$preview.val());   
      }
   });
```

No error message but it isn't performing search on input value.

Comment: Here is a fiddle for this issue.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TauseefJanjua/yrv30f94/17/)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the solution but not proofreading. :-)

**Well, I just resolved this issue by using a small script.**

```
$('#example').DataTable();
$('input[type="search"]').on( 'focus', function () {
        table.search( this.value ).draw();
    });
```

**writing here for others and future reference.**

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`change` callback](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Methods#callbacks) ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fLv6ywz2/)):

```
$(function() {
  var table = $('#example')
    .on('init.dt', function() {
      $('input[type="search"]').keyboard({
        usePreview: false,
        change: function(e, kb) {
          table.search(kb.el.value).draw();
        }
      });
    })
    .DataTable();
});
```

The keyboard is initialized inside the DataTable's init callback. It doesn't appear to be needed, but it's better (less likely to cause a JS error) this way.

Comment: Thanks, it is good to see that it is less likely to cause a JS error.